# How can I bypass a door open error code on an LG top load washer?

Tags: washing-machine, laundry

I have a LG WT7100CW top load washing machine. Right now it won't operate and it keeps throwing up a `dE` error code. Basically it thinks that door is open/it can't lock the door.

I pulled the door lock electro-mechanical device out, opened it up and didn't see anything wrong with it. Tested a few points on it with the multi-meter and everything read fine. I have a repairman coming out to fix it.

However in the meantime, I've got no way to do laundry and the repairman can't get out here for another week. Which brings me to my question.

Is there anyway to convince the washer to ignore this dE code? Or somehow trick it into thinking the door is closed?

Comment: If you get the wiring diagram you might be able to see which wires do what, but no guarantee...

Comment: I would find the switch contact set and jumper them, use caution because if there is a mechanical lock it is probably line voltage but there should be a switch that shows the lock sequence is complete.

Comment: In some cases, the old computer trick applies:  pull the main power plug, wait a few minutes, and plug in again.  With luck, all the status bits will reset and you can use it again.   If not, trace the wires from the switch you tested to make sure it's still solidly plugged into the control board.

Comment: @EdBeal I did try jumpering them with no luck which makes me think its something on the control board end. I checked the connection on the control board and it looked fine as well.

Comment: I missed that in the question, I would think if an input on the control board is bad , that would require more than a jumper.